# How to load a fact table incrementally?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse.dbo.factOrder
(OrderDate, CustomerID, ProductID, OrderAmount)
SELECT o.Date, c.CustomerID, p.ProductID, ISNULL(Amount,0)
FROM Production.dbo.Orders o
INNER JOIN Warehouse.dbo.dimCustomer c
ON o.CustCode = c.CustomerCode
INNER JOIN Warehouse.dbo.dimProduct p
ON o.Code = p.ProductCode;
```

I want to move only Newly inserted or changed Rows from OLTP World into fact table. HOW I can do this by changing in code or schema Presented above?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Nepali Rookie answer my question in a way i want. I want to compare rows at source(OLTP) and destination(DWH) to load only New or changed rows into DWH Fact table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you could use a date field if you have it available to filter out records that you want to do incremental load (also known as delta load) from:

```
INSERT INTO Warehouse.dbo.factOrder
(OrderDate, CustomerID, ProductID, OrderAmount)
SELECT o.Date, c.CustomerID, p.ProductID, ISNULL(Amount,0)
FROM Production.dbo.Orders o
INNER JOIN Warehouse.dbo.dimCustomer c
ON o.CustCode = c.CustomerCode
  and c.RecordCreatedDate > '2015-07-14'
INNER JOIN Warehouse.dbo.dimProduct p
ON o.Code = p.ProductCode 
  and p.RecordCreatedDate > '2015-07-14'
WHERE o.RecordCreatedDate > '2015-07-14'; 
--change this to match your date column name and whatever date you would like to increment 
--(delta load)
```

Comment: Yes, You Got it Right! Normally, in Production environments we have databases with multi-millions rows. we can do incremental loading by comparing those records that were changed or added with those that were loaded into fact tables Previously.                                                                                                          Thanks for the suggestions in code and data.

Comment: @Harry That's wonderful! I figured you would have some kind of field to narrow down your base tables. I am glad that it helped you out, please feel free to mark it as accepted answer at your convenience. :o)

Comment: Thank you Very Very much. But I got another Question: What if i want to track the changes more precisely? For Example, the use of timestamp column or checksum. Secondly, should not we track changes in the fact table? if possible then how

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get what you meant ask in your first question. Do you mean auditing your fact table?

Comment: Yes, i exactly meant of Auditing Fact table. How it can be done?

Comment: For auditing, you could look into creating a new table (like fact_table_audit or something). This table will have exactly the same structure as your fact table except it will also have the recordtimestamp for the audit record. Then, you will want to create a trigger (before insert or update) on your fact table which then will insert a new record in your audit table everytime something is changed in fact table.. That should do it!

Comment: You advised me Very Well @Nepali Rookie. I am very grateful to You. it 's my pleasure to talk with you.

Comment: Same here! I am glad that I could be of some help to you. Good luck on your project! :o)

Comment: Thanks and wish you all the best!

Comment: I know this is an old post.  Just trying to wrap my head around the proposed solution.  Please correct me if I am wrong but in this scenario it is likely that the product has existed long before the order was placed if you inner join on a product that was created before the increment date wouldn't that order be excluded from the Fact? example Product was added last year to inventory, customer places order yesterday, I then use the query above to filter and give me changes for the last week.  The order will not be included in my fact due to the inner join on product. Am I missing something?